# Replace forEach with Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below code

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
List<Integer> myList = getDataForTest(true);
List<String> wordList = getWordList(true);
List<Integer> intList = Collections.emptyList();
intList = myObj.stream().filter(e->e.getType.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")).map(e->e.getIntPos()).collect(Collectors.toList())
AtomicInteger pos = new AtomicInteger(0);
myList.stream()
            .forEach((entry) ->{
                                if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(intList) || intList.contains(pos.get()))
                                {
                                    myMap.computeIfAbsent(myList.get(pos.get()),k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(wordList.get(pos.get()));
                                }
                                pos.incrementAndGet();
                                    });
return myMap;
```

The above code will obviously throw a compilation error as I'm using the **intList** which is not final in the lambda. Is there a way to have this lambda replaced by stream.

Comment: It is of course important to show your code. But equally or perhaps more important is to show what the starting data structures look like with some values and the ultimate desired data structure populated with the those same values.  Please provide an [mre] that does that.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59311742/2711488), the initial assignment of an empty list is obsolete and when you remove it, there is only one assignment left, which allows referencing it from a lambda expression. However, when all you’re gonna do with the collection is to check it for emptiness or calling `contains` on it, you should preferably use a `Set`, to allow a faster lookup:

```
List<Integer> myList = getDataForTest(true);
List<String> wordList = getWordList(true);

Set<Integer> intSet = myObj.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")).map(e -> e.getIntPos())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

IntStream indices = IntStream.range(0, myList.size());
if(!intSet.isEmpty()) indices = indices.filter(intSet::contains);
return indices.boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myList::get,
    TreeMap::new, Collectors.mapping(wordList::get, Collectors.toList())));
```

But there is an alternative. Instead of filtering all list indices by testing their presence in the set, we could iterate over the indices of the set in the first place. We only have to make them sorted and distinct, to be encountered the same way as the `range` indices that passed the filter. For this kind of operation, an array of primitive `int` values is more suitable:

```
List<Integer> myList = getDataForTest(true);
List<String> wordList = getWordList(true);

int[] ints = myObj.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")).mapToInt(e -> e.getIntPos())
    .sorted().distinct()
    .toArray();

return (ints.length == 0? IntStream.range(0, myList.size()): Arrays.stream(ints))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myList::get, TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(wordList::get, Collectors.toList())));
```

Without the special treatment of “no indices” as “no filtering”, we could even do it in a single stream operation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's your actual code, why not just make it final? Replace

```
List<Integer> intList = Collections.emptyList();
intList = myObj.stream().filter(e->e.getType.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")).map(e->e.getIntPos()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

with

```
final List<Integer> intList = myObj.stream().filter(e -> e.getType.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")).map(e -> e.getIntPos()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Other than that, I don't think it's possible to replace your forEach with a stream because you're not actually doing anything with the `entry`s of the list as you iterate through the list. In fact I'm not quite sure what you're actually trying to accomplish. But why not replace it with a simple for loop?

```
for (Integer myVal : myList){
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(intList) || intList.contains(pos.get())){
        myMap.computeIfAbsent(myList.get(pos.get()), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(wordList.get(pos.get()));
    }
    pos.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: The OP’s code doesn’t use the `entry` parameter, but uses `myList.get(pos.get())` which evaluates to the same value. Note that when using a loop, you can use a plain `int` variable instead of the `AtomicInteger`. Further, there is no need for the 3rd party library class `CollectionUtils` here, is the only difference between `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(intList)` and a straight-forward `intList.isEmpty()` is the treatment of `null`, but `intList` is never `null` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this for a while and came up with a solution based on my own list
of test data.

Given the following:

```
      List<Integer> myList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 2);
      List<String> wordList = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
      List<Integer> intList = List.of(1, 4, 2);
```

This stream solution

```
      AtomicInteger pos = new AtomicInteger(-1);
      System.out.println(myMap);
      Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap2 = myList.stream().filter(
            d ->!intList.isEmpty() &&
                  intList.contains(pos.incrementAndGet())).collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d,
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(d -> wordList.get(pos.get()),
                              Collectors.toList())));
      System.out.println(myMap2);
```

and your solution produce

> {2=[B, E], 3=[C]}

I'm sure it could be adjusted to provide what you want.

However, there is nothing wrong with using a regular `forEach` loop on `myList`.  It also permits you to get rid of the `atomic integer` because there is no `effective final` restriction.

```java
      int i = 0;
      for (int entry : myList) {
         if (!intList.isEmpty() && intList.contains(i)) {
            System.out.println("entry = " + entry);
            myMap.computeIfAbsent(myList.get(i), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(
                  wordList.get(i));
         }
         i++;
      }
```

Comment: Kaboom!  Thanks.  I believe I fixed it (it works with an empty list and also as before). 
 But I still don't know exactly what the OP wants.  I'll just wait and see if they respond.